# Detecting utf8 encoding errors

Tags: php

While working with Froogle, the datafeed is constantly bugging me with encoding problems in some article-descriptions.

The script, string and output is utf8 encoded, but I can't find the characters that cause the problem.

is there a way to detect troublesome characters?

Comment: What kind of problems? Are you finding values that are not valid UTF-8 code points, or are you having a case of Mojibake? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake

Comment: Nothing of that kind. Google just tells me "there is an encoding problem somewhere in this text"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the **[htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)** function for your string.

```
echo htmlentities($your_str, ENT_QUOTES);
```

And **then** use, `html_entity_decode` function to read back with **utf8** as parameter.

Comment: tried that already with
html_entity_decode($products_description,ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8');
helped for some strings, others are still having the same problm

Comment: to get this finally closed: Normally this method should work, the problem is somewhere on googles side. Haven't found the real problem yet, tho